# Constructor with many arguments

Tags: go

What's the most idiomatic way of initializing a Go type with many required parameters?

For example:

```
type Appointment struct {
  Title string
  Details string
  Dresscode string

  StartingTime int64
  EndingTime int64
  RSVPdate int64


  Place *Place
  Guests []*Guest
}

type Place struct {
  Name string
  Address string
}

type Guest struct {
  Name string
  Status string
}
```

I want the `Appointment` type to be always valid; that is, I don't want to  initialize it with a struct literal and then have to validate it.

Don't want:

```
a := &Appointment{
  Title: "foo",
  Details: "bar",
  StartingTime: 12451412,
  ...
}

err := a.Validate()
```

whats the best way to initialize this type of object (with lots of fields) without having to supply all the arguments in the constructor arguments?

Comment: How will the compiler know how to initialize the object if you don't tell it? Are you trying to say you want to initialize it in many places with the same arguments? If that's the case, you could define a couple functions to manage the state of the object (e.g. `CreateAppointment()`)

Comment: If you want to make sure it's always valid, you'll have to retain tight control over access to the fields. To do that, you can put the type definitions in their own package so that you can only export what you want to export. If you don't want to have your "constructor" function take a bunch of arguments, you can define a structure that contains all the initialization parameters and pass that. (That's just a general way of making a function with a long argument list easier to use.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way you could avoid having to pass 10+ arguments to your constructors is to have an `XxxParams` type for each of your `Xxx` types and have your `NewXxx` take that params type as its argument. Then the `NewXxx` constructor would construct an `Xxx` value from those params, validate it, and return it, or an error, depending on the result of the validation.

This might feel redundant if you're constructing the `XxxParams` values manually as opposed to unmarshaling them from json, xml, etc.; but still, this way you are enforcing, however loosely, only valid `Xxx`'s to be constructed, keeping the possibly invalid state in the input (`XxxParams`).

Here's an example from Stripe's repo: [Account](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/blob/c4fbb41e6d772a7571bdc31eea0d4de7c2450ee4/account.go#L88-L132), [AccountParams](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/blob/c4fbb41e6d772a7571bdc31eea0d4de7c2450ee4/account.go#L54-L65), and [constructor](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/blob/c4fbb41e6d772a7571bdc31eea0d4de7c2450ee4/account/client.go#L106-L125)

Comment: These links would be great except that they reference the master branch of these files which have definitely changed, so the highlights dont line up anymore.

Answer (score 9):

You may be able to use the "[functional options](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/10/17/functional-options-for-friendly-apis)" pattern to achieve this. It allows you to define functions for each input, removing the need for you to pass lots of options to your constructor.

```
func New(options ...func(*Appointment)) (*Appointment, error) {
  ap := &Appointment{
    Title: "Set your defaults",
    Details: "if you don't want zero values",
    StartingTime: 123,
  }
  for _, option := range options {
    option(ap)
  }
  // Do any final validation that you want here.
  // E.g. check that something is not still 0 value
  if ap.EndTime == 0 {
    return nil, errors.New("invalid end time")
  }

  return ap, nil
}

// Then define your option functions

func AtEndTime(endTime int64) func(*Appointment) {
  return func(ap *Appointment) {
    ap.EndTime = endTime
  }       
}
```

The resulting call looks something like:

```
ap, err := appointment.New(
  AtEndTime(123),
  WithGuests([]Guest{...}),
)
```

If you want to validate each option in the function itself, it's not too much work to change that signature to possibly return an error too.

Comment: Thanks for the link; this is clever but still quite verbose imo. I can see how it would work well for setting up (optional) options though, but not so much for datatypes with many required fields where default values are not possible.

Comment: That link there is gold. I think this should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One pattern seen used by popular Go project is to create functions that return desired state of a struct. (checkout the [httprouter](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter) project as an example - although its `New` func does not take any args...)

In your case - you could write a function that returns an `Appointment` with desired properties initialized.

for example

```
package appointment 

type Appointment struct { 
    //your example code here...
}

func New(title, details, dressCode string) *Appointment {
  return &Appointment{
    Title: "foo",
    Details: "bar",
    StartingTime: 12451412,
    //set the rest of the properties with sensible defaults - otherwise they will initialize to their zero value
  }  
}
```

Then used in another file, import the package

```
package main

import path/to/appointment

func main() {
   myApt := appointment.New("Interview", "Marketing Job", "Casual")
   //myApt is now a pointer to an Appointment struct properly initialized
}
```

Depending on how tight you want access control of the Appointment object property values, you do not have to export all of them (by setting them to lowercase) and provide more traditional accessor (think get, set) methods on the struct itself to ensure the struct always remain "valid"

Answer (score 0):

> I want the `Appointment` type to be always valid; that is, I don't want to initialize it with a struct literal and then have to validate it.

The only way to guarantee this is to not export the type. Then the only way for a consumer of your package to obtain a struct of that type, is through your constructor method.  Keep in mind that returning non-exported types is kind of ugly. One possible way around this is to access your data through an exported interface. That brings in a number of other considerations--which may be good, or bad for any given situation.

Now, while that's the only way to strictly meet your stated requirement, it may not actually be necessary. You might consider relaxing your requirement.

Consider this:

### You must validate input data!

All you're deciding on is whether you're doing the validation at object creation time, or at object consumption time.  Go's constructs generally make the latter easier (for both the coder, and the consumer of the data).  If you *truly must* do validation at object creation time, then your only option is to use unexported types, and getter/setter methods for everything.

Comment: Good points, but it makes life easier imo when type invariants are never allowed to enter into an invalid state. After all, is a car presumed to be a car without four wheels and an engine? Plus, if you're validating at consumption time you're really relying on developers to remember to call `Validate()` each time which they may or may not do. 

>You must validate input data! 
agreed, but that can be done using some kind of data container before ever instantiating the object.

Comment: @user7467314: How is your data type being consumed? Why would a `Validate()` function be needed, rather than, say, a `SaveToDatabase()` function, which also does validation?

Comment: something like `SaveToDatabse()` would be the concern of the persistence mechanism which probably won't deal with validation at all. Validation will be implemented as behaviours on the model. As to how the data is consumed, a service layer instantiates the model from some data, executes whatever behaviours it needs to and then persists the object to the database.

Comment: As you say, invariants will need to be preserved after each state transition. The problem is how do you instantiate models that have a lot of state that can't really be grouped together logically, for e.g in a single struct. How do you avoid having to call a constructor with 10+ argument primitives?